# C# DateTime to Javascript Date - Timezones

Tags: javascript, c#, date, datetime

I have a string `2016-01-04T15:30:00` coming from c# DateTime.
When I convert it to a javascript
 `Date` object `var jDate = new Date(2016-01-04T15:30:00);`
the time is getting changed based on the local time zone 
Console Output: `Mon Jan 04 2016 10:30:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`
How can I get the date to have the time `15:30` and not `10:30`?

The answer should return a Date object so I can do `date.getHours()`

Comment: Try this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: I need a Date object because I use it to get the hours,min... I'm just not getting the correct time

Comment: `jDate.getUTCHours()` will give you `15`.

Comment: Thanks, this is all I needed for my code to work because I don't care what the time is on the date itself

Answer (score 1):

You need to cahnge the DateTime Kind to **Unspecified**,

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(saveNow, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Read more here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just a tip: indent code by four spaces to make a code sample